# NGINX proxy pass to Node.JS server SSL handshake failure

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, proxypass, nginx-reverse-proxy

I want to setup a reverse proxy with NGINX to my express.js server, but when connecting to the website i receive a Cloudflare `525 SSL handshake failed` error.

This is my NGINX configuration file

```
# Redirect IP queries

server {
        listen 80;
        server_name MyIP;

        return 301 $scheme://example.com;
}

server {
        listen 443;
        server_name MyIP;

        ssl_certificate /home/ubuntu/Website/ssl/certificate.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /home/ubuntu/Website/ssl/key.pem;

        return 301 $scheme://example.com;
}

# Reverse proxy

server {
        listen 80;
        server_name example.com;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
        }
}

server {
        listen 443;
        server_name example.com;

        location / {
                proxy_pass https://localhost:8080;
                proxy_ssl_certificate /home/ubuntu/Website/ssl/certificate.pem;
                proxy_ssl_certificate_key /home/ubuntu/Website/ssl/key.pem;
        }
}
```

And the same certificate is being used on the express.js application too:

```js
// Start the server
// Get SSL certificate data
const privateKey = fs.readFileSync(path.join(dirName(import.meta.url), "../ssl/key.pem"));
const certificate = fs.readFileSync(path.join(dirName(import.meta.url), "../ssl/certificate.pem"));
http.createServer(app).listen(5000);
https.createServer({
    key: privateKey,
    cert: certificate
}, app).listen(8080);
console.log("Server online");
```

Comment: Your `server` blocks for 443 are missing ssl certificates.

Comment: Do you mean I have to add SSL certificates to the IP redirect too?

Comment: That's not a redirect, that's a reverse proxy and yes, nginx does SSL termination here and needs a certificate.

Comment: But even for the redirect IP -> domain you need a valid certificate (that contains the IP address)

Comment: I updated the IP server block in the question with the SSL certificate directives but I'm still getting the same error. How can i add the IP to the certificate? Do i have to create a self signed one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add valid TLS certificate to the `server` block for `example.com`. Your current configuration means that nginx is using the default self-signed certificates, and Cloudflare considers them invalid.

Redirecting IP address to the domain name isn't needed in my opinion. I prefer just to have 404 sent to requests to the IP address, which would be handled by the `default_server` block . And you cannot get anything else than self-signed certificates for IP addresses.

Comment: That's what I did, just forgot to post the answer here. As for the IP redirect, I need it to remove the result from the Google index

Comment: When you have the default `server` block return 404 not found, then Google will realise there is nothing on the IP address and it will remove the results. You can also likely remove the content by adding the IP address to Google Search Console and submitting content removal request there.

Comment: I tried using search console but the IP was not considered my property, I also preferred 301 so that the result was not removed from Google but rather replaced.